# "having dinner" vs "having had dinner"

Tags: tense, clauses

> "I have my dinner and go to my work."

If I change this sentence, which one is more correct?

> (a) Having dinner; I go to my work.
>   (b) Having had my dinner; I go to my work.

Comment: "I *had* my dinner and *go* to my work" is grammatically incorrect. You might want to change that to "have".

Comment: You should write:I had my dinner and went to work.

Answer (score 3):

We rarely say 'I go to *my* work' - it's usually 'I go to work'.

If you are talking about what you usually do each day, then 'I have dinner then go to work' sounds the most natural.

'Having dinner...' isn't right, as you would say that if you were about to describe something that happened whilst you were in the process of eating dinner one time.

'Having had dinner...' can be used, but we usually use this 'having had' construct to refer to an action previously mentioned e.g. 'I have dinner at 6 o'clock. Having had dinner, I go to work.'

Comment: "Having had dinner, I go to work." is a weird construct. If you were talking about general plans or scheduling you could say "After having dinner, I go to work." If talking about something that already happened it would be "Having had dinner, I went to work."

Comment: "I usually shower about 5:50 in the morning. Having had my shower, I get dressed and go to work" - this is talking about what you usually do, not any specific instance. "I work nights, so have dinner about 6. Having had dinner, I go to work.". It's a bit formal and most people would say 'after' instead of 'having had' e.g. "I have dinner about 6. After dinner/after that, I go to work."